# Unable to pull values from list with threshold limit from rest api

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list with around 30000 items.
This list has threshold limit applied to 15000 and throttling enabled on the list. In the rest api url, i am trying to filter a lookup column.

Now when i query the list with rest api filtering a lookup column, i am getting below error
"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."
If i filter on any other column, i am getting result set.

Please suggest how to get the values for lookup column without list view threshold error.

Thanks in advance
Usha

Comment: Have you found any solution for above problem?